# Subsetting a file into multiple files based on a value in the last two positions of the record in the file using powershell

Tags: unix, powershell, awk

I want to subset a file into multiple txt files based on a value in the last two positions of the record in the file in powershell. The source file is from IBM z/OS machine and it does not have file extension. What i currently do is use a awk command to subset it based on the values in the last two positions of the record in the file like below

```
awk '{print > "file.txt" substr($0,length-2,2) }' RAW
```

The file name is RAW and it creates multiple files depending on the last two distinct values in a record. So if AA is the value in the last two position of the record of the file. i would get a file outputted like fileAA.txt. How can i achieve this in powershell?

Thanks

Comment: Would love to help, but can't get my head around what you're asking.  When you say "last two positions" - do you mean last two bytes, or are you treating the file as a series of structs/records?  I'm not familiar with the likes of CED/AWK, so the example doesn't help me either!  But, long story short, yes PowerShell will be able to do it... just need to understand what it is you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
Get-Content RAW | %{ $fn="file"+$_.Substring($_.length-2)+".txt"; $_ | Out-File $fn -Append; }
```

Comment: I'm guessing there might be more than one line which ends in `AA`, and you'll be `Out-File`ing each line one at a time, so you should probably add the `-Append` switch to the `Out-File` command.

Comment: @robert.westerlund Thanks! I am not familiar with powershell, I just googled it now.

Comment: It was just a suggestion so you could edit and update your answer. Just hoping to help improve it.

Comment: Hopefully none of the records have illegal characters in the last two characters. Such as a line ending in `6:` would throw an error: `Out-File : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'file6' does not exist.` Or one that ended in `\G` would throw: `Out-File : Illegal characters in path.` Other than that this looks like a great answer.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Thanks for the comment! The OP should clarify if special treatment is required.

Comment: Thanks all for the inputs. There is no special treatment required. the value in the last two position within the file is in the range of P0 through P9 and RO through R9. the file has around 1 million lines/records/rows and each line/record/row ends in one of the values mentioned above.